# Understanding expectation operatior with an example : Matlab

Tags: matlab, math, statistics

Say, I have `N` observations stored in an array, `X = [x_1,x_2,...,x_N]`. What is the meaning of `E[\sum_{i=1}^N{x_i}]/N`? This to me appears an average operation. But not sure. Can somebody please help what is the meaning of this operator with the help of any example in Matlab?

In general, (1) what is `E[x]~ where`x`is a random variable,
 (2)`E[x^2]`, and
(3)`E[d]`where`d = 1/N(sum_{i=1}^N x_i)`

Comment: The formatting of the expectation formula is critical.  Could you try again? What you have there is nonsense and could mean a couple different things depending on how you modify it.

Comment: The way you put it yes, it seems to me too that this is just an average. The "E" operation if it is expectation shouldn't have any effect whatsoever, so it is probably a special function. Can you provide more details? Some references?

Comment: @Brick: I have updated the question, please let me know if now it makes sense or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your notation is still pretty bad to the point it's hard to understand, BUT there's a limit to what you can do on this site since it does not have MathJax enabled...

The expectation value is a *generalized* average in the sense that it should be weighted by the distribution from which `X` is drawn.  *If X is uniformly distributed* then you'll get what you would call the "average" and what I think your first formula is giving.  If `X` is distributed by some other distribution, then you will get something else.

If the distribution is discrete, then in general

```
E[f(x)] = sum_{i=1}^N [f(x_i) p(x_i)],
```

where p(x) is the distribution for the random variable.

Comment: I did not understand the formula given by you. In general, for an array of numbers generated from gaussiandistribution, how would I calculate the expectation?

Comment: If they are distributed as Gaussian, then p(x_i) is the Gaussian density function evaluated at sample x_i in that case.

Comment: THen how does one plot and what is f(x_i)? Say, I want to plot the power of the signal, the formula of which is `E[X^2]` If mean is not zero, then how do I plot the variance or the power whose analytical formula is `var_x = E[X] - E^[X]` I cannot visualize what these terms look like without an implementation.

Comment: If you want E[x^2] then f(x) = x^2.